# Making text larger in CSS using ":hover" and making it revert to it's smaller (initial state)

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

Let me explain what I'm trying to achieve.

I have text on my website that I want to make LARGER when the user mouses over and SMALLER when the user leaves the hover.

The problem is when I make it larger like so using the `:hover` method in CSS I can't revert back to it's previous (initial) state afterwards.

```
#sname{
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    color: rgba(1,1,1,0.7);
}

#sname a{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 4em;
}

#sname a:hover{
    font-size:88px;
    transition: all 500ms;
    font-size-adjust: 20px;

}
```

I'm kinda stuck, I've tried `not:(:hover)` but it doesn't do anything, and I've also used `:onmouseleave`

---

This is a website for a college project, my work is mostly completed (Had to link it to a DB) but I just want to make it look nicer through CSS, I'd use javascript but have little knowledge of how it works.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle example?

Comment: Show us your HTML structure, because it should work (http://jsfiddle.net/xfgnaw9a/1/)

Comment: *"I have text on my website that I want to make LARGER when the user mouses over and SMALLER when the user leaves the hover."* Design- and UX-wise, this is very probably a bad idea.

Comment: You forgot to close some curly brackets in you css rules ... that was the problem ...

Comment: Tomalak, could you elaborate? Interested.

Comment: Text that moves/resizes on mouseover... A) distorts the experience when you just want to get the mouse to a certain point and the element in question is in your path. B) It triggers unnecessary and irritating page re-renders/text wraps/visual glitches/layout changes. C) It gets visually tiring very quickly. 500ms is a very long time, you don't really want to have moving and zooming stuff on your page *all the time* with no usability benefit *at all*. Think about how annoying this is if you have to get actual work done. D) Also, "mouseover" is not a meainingful interaction on mobile devices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to add the transition to `#sname a` (and close the css block):

```css
#sname {
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    color: rgba(1,1,1,0.7);
}

#sname a {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 4em;
    transition: all 500ms;
}
    
#sname a:hover {
    font-size:88px;
    font-size-adjust: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sname">
    <a href="#">test</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Then you can omit the `transition` from `:hover` state.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, you just need to move the transition to the initial a state and close the brackets in your css :)

```css
#sname {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.7);
}
#sname a {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 4em;
  transition: all 500ms;
}
#sname a:hover {
  font-size: 88px;
  font-size-adjust: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sname">
  <a href="#">IT WORKS</a>
</div>
```